# What is the _SYSCRT macro for in MSVC C++ CRT?

Tags: visual-studio, msvcrt, visual-c++-runtime

When I browse through VC CRT sources, I sometimes see two separate implementations (for example, the `new` operator), one for when `_SYSCRT` is defined and another for when `_SYSCRT` is undefined.

Now, `_SYSCRT` may well be undocumented but I'm debugging CRT code and `_SYSCRT` is right there in my face. So the question is: should I assume it **defined** or **not defined** during "normal use"?

By "normal use" I mean linking with a Win32 user-mode application in MSVC 2015.

Comment: It begins with an underscore and a capital letter, so it is reserved for the implementation and you should not be using it.

Comment: @RaymondChen : The "reserved for implementation" rule merely means that you should not define macros with such names, not that you cannot use them.  The question does not ask about using it, but rather what it is for;  "reserved for implementation" does not prohibit curiosity either!

Comment: `_SYSCRT` is not documented. therefore, don't define it, don't conditionalize on it, don't use it.

Comment: I'm not going to use it. I want to know what it is for. So that I better understand how the crt works.

Comment: The group at Microsoft that maintains the CRT has a pretty difficult customer.  Microsoft.  And Raymond.  They can innovate on the CRT as necessary to implement evolving language standards but they can't break the operating system.  `_BOOTCRT_` looks like another one.